# O que é lusofonia?

Tags: expressões, vocabulário

O que é lusofonia? Em que situações posso utilizar esse termo? Vi ele alguns dias mas fiquei sem entender qual o significado dele.

Gostaria de exemplos.

Answer (score 2):

**Lusofonia**, de *"luso-"* (português) + *"-fonia"* (relacionado a som ou voz) é um substantivo que se refere ao conjunto de nações, comunidades, povos e culturas falantes da língua portuguesa (ver definições [aqui](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lusofonia) e [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusofonia)). Há também o adjetivo **"lusófono"**, usado para atribuir a um povo ou nação a qualidade de ser falante da língua portuguesa. Por exemplo:

- A lusofonia europeia é composta por Portugal e por pequenas comunidades em outros países.
- Espanha e Uruguai não são nações lusófonas, mas possuem dentro de si algumas comunidades lusófonas formada por imigrantes portugueses e brasileiros.